# Error 4 in libmysqlclient_r.so.16.0.0

Tags: mysql, asterisk, centos6

I keep getting the following message in `/var/log/messages`:

> kernel: asterisk[14069]: segfault at 338 ip 00007f018322f887 sp 00007f016506abc8 error 4 in libmysqlclient_r.so.16.0.0[7f018320c000+139000]

Then Asterisk crashes and reloads
Can I please get some advice on this one.

System Spec:

- CentOS Linux 6.7 (2.6.32-573.7.1.el6.x86_64)
- Asterisk 1.8.32.3
- MySQL Cluster 7.4.7
- MySQL Nodes 5.6.25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likly you have mysql-client-devel for different version of mysql.

Best option is deinstall all mysql libs, reinstall mysql, ensure mysql devel is same version, after that rebuild asterisk.

Comment: I shall try this first thing Monday and report my results. Thank you

Comment: `yum list installed | grep mysql
mysql.x86_64                             5.1.73-5.el6_6  @base
mysql-connector-odbc.x86_64
mysql-devel.x86_64                     5.1.73-5.el6_6  @base
mysql-libs.x86_64                        5.1.73-5.el6_6  @anaconda-CentOS-201508042137.x86_64/6.7
nagios-plugins-mysql.x86_64
php-mysql.x86_64                       5.3.3-46.el6_6  @updates
`

Comment: arrr yes, I see now...
I have upgraded the mysql-libs.x86_64 to 5.5.46-1.el6
So hopefully this should be a little more stable

Comment: I now appear to be getting the following:
'kernel: asterisk[17473]: segfault at f20 ip 00007f2822c5808d sp 00007f27f1b59d10 error 4 in libodbc.so.2.0.0[7f2822c36000+5f000]'

Comment: SO is not debug site. Check your setup or hire linux admin.

Comment: Removed all references to the mysql libraries and reinstalled. Then did a rebuild of asterisk and now the odbc is much more stable. Thanks.